Volatility Surface Modelling in Python
For my master thesis, I try to create a Volatility Surface for S&P500 Index options. Every time I run my code, the surface I get is full of spikes.
I'm just not sure if these are outliers which distort the surface (weird option contracts in my dataset) or if this is more like a sign that my calculations for the Implied Volatilities are wrong. I'm using interpolation and extrapolation in that case, but I've also tried without these techniques, and it still looks pretty similar.
I would appreciate any information or help.
Thanks everyone!


Definitely outliers. You should consider using a filtering algorithm in your options dataset.

You might find this explanation useful.

Thank you for your answers! I will try to find some filtering algorithms that make sense in that case.  I'm still a bit confused looking at the graph since I don't understand how negative values for IV can even show up (negative spikes).
